# Question about eShopOnContainers api gateway route prefix

Tags: c#, .net, microservices, api-gateway

There is project called [eShopOnContainer](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers), it's a .NET Microservices Sample Reference Aplication, powered by Microsoft, based on a simplified microservices architecture and Docker containers.

They are using [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) as a reverse proxy on API Gateway, you can see more about it [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/wiki/BFF-implementation). The Envoy is configured with the following rules:

- Routes with prefix "**/c/**" forwards to "**/catalog-api/**" (Catalog microservice)
- Routes with prefix "**/o/**" forwards to "**/ordering-api/**" (Order microservice)
- Routes with prefix "**/b/**" forwards to "**/basket-api/**" (Basket microservice)

This application has an eBook that explain many decisions taken, there is a section where they talk about this topic: **Why consider API Gateways instead of direct client-to-microservice communication** and this is one of the reasons:

> **Coupling**: Without the API Gateway pattern, the client apps are coupled to the internal microservices. **The client apps need to know how the multiple areas of the application are decomposed in microservices**. When evolving and refactoring the internal microservices, those actions impact maintenance because they cause breaking changes to the client apps due to the
> direct reference to the internal microservices from the client apps. Client apps need to be updated frequently, making the solution harder to evolve.

So I was thinking, the fact of using a prefix on the route generete a problem: "The client apps need to know how the multiple areas of the application are decomposed in microservices", right? So is it an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 0):

regardless of microservices architecture or monolith architecture, this statement always stay true

> The client apps need to know how the multiple areas of the application are decomposed in microservices

With typical monolith application, you'll have to config the application routing in your **application business logic**, either with route prefix, or route area

Now, with api gateway and microservices architecture, you'll achieve a few things as below

- your application only expose small set of APIs
- the routing will be configured in the network infra layer (`host/a/api/...` route to `a-service`), often combine with multiple middlewares (for example: strip the /a/ prefix from the origin url, ip whitelisting, audit, authn & authz, etc)
- better observability with lots of paid & free tools
- the service can be replaced/swapped quite easily
- complex routing with blue/green and/or canary deployments, possibly with automated traffic testing & service promotion
- and more....